# Include .dll .pak .bin in .exe

Tags: electron, exe

I have create a electron app with javascript. 
I have multiple file's namely: 
  .bin 
  .pak 
  .dll 
and the .exe

In total there are between 15 and 25 file's. 
Is it possible to include all my .dll .bin .pak file's in my .exe so that there will be one big .exe file ?

I have already looked up asar and that worked but I get a .asar file and not a .exe and then I can't execute my .asar file

I now have 15-25 file's(.dll .bin .pak) and the .exe
I want to have one .exe including all the .dll .bin .pak file's.

Comment: Could it be that you just want to create an SFX archive? See 
https://superuser.com/questions/283698/create-7-zip-sfx-executable

Comment: no not exactly. I want that al my .dll .pak and .bin files are 'inside' my .exe and with the sfx archive I still have the .dll .pak and .dll besides my .exe @fgk